# Laravel mass-assignment doesnt insert boolean

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to do the mass assignment with laravel like. But I have a field called 'hidden' that in the database is a TINYINT. From my front-end I get a boolean back. When I mass-assign with 'hidden' => TRUE the field in DB still is 0. When i convert it back to a integer ('hidden' => 1) then the field is saved as 1.

I did added 'hidden' to my $fillable.

P.S. When I try inserting it into DB directy with mysql with boolean value, it works.

Anyone know what is wrong?

EDIT: this is my code,

public function store(Request $request) {

class Group extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;

```
const CREATED_AT = 'created';
const UPDATED_AT = 'updated';

protected $table = 'groups';

protected $casts = [
    'hidden' => 'boolean',
];

protected $fillable = [
    'hidden',
     // etc
];
```

}

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $post = $request->all();
    $group_id = Group::create($post);
}
```

Front-end is Vue project. So laravel is my API. And I do get a TRUE out of $post['hidden'].

Comment: Can you post your form and controller too, so that we can see what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the boolean in the model:

```
class YourModel extends Model
{

    protected $casts = [
        'hidden' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

This will tell Laravel the you want the `hidden` column to be treated as boolean and values like 0 and 1 will be returned as true/false and true/false saved as 0/1.
You can read more in [Laravel doc mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting).

Answer (score 0):

Change the database type to Bool. If you want to do that with a migration you can do: $table->boolean(‘hidden’);

Comment: That will convert it just to a TINYINT in database, what it is already

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn’t aware of this. Your not inserting true/false values as strings from the front end, are you?

Comment: Haha am gonna kill myself. I use a library for front-end elements, the element returns the boolean as a string... That was it.